# Cat walks through-neath the table?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, prepositions

I want to say that the cat walks under the table, but also that he entered on the one side and exitted on the other side. It is not that he is just walking around beneath the table.

So the cat is not doing this:

[image: enter image here]

But doing this:

[image]

What is the correct way of describing this?

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is _"the cat passed under the table"_

Comment: @ColleenV "passed" can work. But what if I wanted to specify the way in which he is doing it. Lets say crawling or jumping

Comment: I agree it's not a great choice, which is why I didn't make it an answer. Maybe a little more context would help spark some ideas. You could say _"The cat dashed under the table and out the other side."_

Comment: I think "through-neath" is an __AWESOME__ coinage, and I'm going to adopt it forthwith!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The cat walks under the table*.

could be interpreted as either of the scenarios you've depicted in your two sketches.

If you want to eliminate ambiguity, so that it's clear which of the scenarios you mean, you could say:

> *The cat goes under the table **and walks out the other end**.*

Comment: Sure, I understand. It just seems so unnecessarily long though. Was hoping there is an old word that went extinct long ago, which would have the same meaning as "through-neath"

Answer (score 1):

I would actually interpret "the cat walked under the table" as indicating that it entered on one side and left on the other. "the cat walked underneath the table" sounds a bit strange to me. That's everyday usage, partially driven by context that makes walking around and around in circles under a table a bit strange, even for cats. I'm not sure what the formal rules are here.

Comment: Wouldn't "walked underneath" simply imply that it stayed there?

Comment: I think it's closer to indicating that the cat stayed there than 'under', but it's probably a bit ambiguous. I'd say "Walked around underneath the table" to imply that it was going in circles under the table.